# jquery $('head').append and facebook share

Tags: jquery, facebook, append, share, head

i thought this was going to be simple but i don't know why is not working...

When you make facebook share button and you want some special image on the fb share, you put something like this in the `<head>` of the page:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="image.jpg" />
```

Facebook will then grab this image and put it in the post.

but i create this image after the page is loaded. so i wanted to put this piece of code into the  after the page is loaded. I tried with this code:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="image_src" href="image.jpg" />');
```

but for some reason it doesnt work?

so how do i do that - append this piece of code into page  after the page is loaded AND that facebook share button will grab this image?

thank you, Peter

Answer (score 0):

you can check how facebook reads your site here:
[URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/)

i think they only process html without executed javascript

Answer (score 0):

The share-window loads the HTML of the site you want to share after you've clicked the share button. I personally don't think that it is able to execute JavaScript. Even if it could, it would have a different session and post-data. Also it get's cached.

In my experience it's just parsing the HTML without executing JavaScript.
If you use XFBML you could **try** calling `FB.XFBML.parse();` after you appended the image, but I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the Open Graph tags instead could be a solution

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Here's some more information, with examples:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/